# Implementing a bytecode generating JSON parser

Tags: java, json

I'm implementing a function that should parse a lot (multiple terabytes) of JSON data with schema known before processing.

```
Iterator<JsonObject> parseJson(Schema schema, Iterator<String> data) {
    var parser = createParser(schema);

    return new Iterator<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return data.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public JsonObject next() {
            return parser.parse(data.next());
        }
    };
}
```

I want to leverage the fact that schema is known to parse it as fast as possible. Are there some existing solutions, like using Jackson Blackbird but constructing it from my custom schema object instead of a class? Will it be worth it even though the result is not a class but a generic JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there some existing solutions, like using Jackson Blackbird but constructing it from my custom schema object instead of a class?

I'm not aware of any.

It is worth noting the following from the Blackbird README file:

> *"Blackbird has been lightly performance tested using jmh on openjdk 11 and 12. For reading and writing a moderately complex bean, Blackbird performance seems to be almost exactly on par with Afterburner - up to 20% better than vanilla Jackson in some cases."*

"Up to 20% better" is not a huge improvement, especially when that is qualified with "in some cases".

> Will it be worth it even though the result is not a class but a generic JSON object?

1. I don't think that an improvement of "up to 20%" is going to be worth the effort of developing your own solution.  (However that's just my opinion.  For all I know, a 20% improvement *could* be a deal-maker ... for you.)
2. Blackbird and the older Afterburner got much of their performance improvement by avoiding reflection when operating on (reading or constructing) POJOs.  If you are using a `JSONObject` representation or similar instead of POJOs, you no longer have that aspect to (potentially) optimize.

---

When I first read this question, I thought "Hey, why not translate your custom schemas into grammars suitable for ANTLR or JavaCC or similar, and then generate fast parsers?"

But it won't work.  The problem is tokenization.  Unfortunately in the JSON language, string literals are used both as primitive values and as attribute names in objects.  And a conventional grammar notation cannot express something like "a string token whose value is "xyz".

I guess you might be able to fudge it with a context sensitive lexer, but my guess that would have performance downsides that would tend to negate the benefits of an efficient PGS generated parser.

Another approach might be to treat individual characters as tokens.  That would be horrible if you were writing the grammar by hand, but for a generated grammar (that nobody needs to read) it might be practical.  (Or not.  For example, the generated grammars could turn out to be unsuitable for a PGS.  It gets technical ...)

However ... it might work.  But you won't find out until someone tries it and then *measures* how much performance improvement they actually got for all of the developer effort expended.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know about existing solutions, here is something similar to what you've tried, but using streams, maybe it helps:

```
public Stream<JsonObject> parseJson(Schema schema, Iterator<String> data) {
    var parser = createParser(schema);
    return streamFrom(data).map(parser::parse);
}

public static <T> Stream<T> streamFrom(Iterator<T> iterator) {
    Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator;
    boolean inParallel = false;
    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), inParallel);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of implementing a JSON parser manually, I prefer to parse the JSON with a library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). `mapper.readTree` would be useful for parsing JSON instantly even if the length of String is large.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
String jsonString = "{\"products\":[{\"id\":1,\"title\":\"iPhone 9\",\"description\":\"An apple mobile which is nothing like apple\",\"price\":549,\"discountPercentage\":12.96,\"rating\":4.69,\"stock\":94,\"brand\":\"Apple\",\"category\":\"smartphones\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":2,\"title\":\"iPhone X\",\"description\":\"SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD display with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...\",\"price\":899,\"discountPercentage\":17.94,\"rating\":4.44,\"stock\":34,\"brand\":\"Apple\",\"category\":\"smartphones\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":3,\"title\":\"Samsung Universe 9\",\"description\":\"Samsung's new variant which goes beyond Galaxy to the Universe\",\"price\":1249,\"discountPercentage\":15.46,\"rating\":4.09,\"stock\":36,\"brand\":\"Samsung\",\"category\":\"smartphones\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/3/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/3/1.jpg\"]},{\"id\":4,\"title\":\"OPPOF19\",\"description\":\"OPPO F19 is officially announced on April 2021.\",\"price\":280,\"discountPercentage\":17.91,\"rating\":4.3,\"stock\":123,\"brand\":\"OPPO\",\"category\":\"smartphones\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/4/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":5,\"title\":\"Huawei P30\",\"description\":\"Huawei’s re-badged P30 Pro New Edition was officially unveiled yesterday in Germany and now the device has made its way to the UK.\",\"price\":499,\"discountPercentage\":10.58,\"rating\":4.09,\"stock\":32,\"brand\":\"Huawei\",\"category\":\"smartphones\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/5/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/5/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/5/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/5/3.jpg\"]},{\"id\":6,\"title\":\"MacBook Pro\",\"description\":\"MacBook Pro 2021 with mini-LED display may launch between September, November\",\"price\":1749,\"discountPercentage\":11.02,\"rating\":4.57,\"stock\":83,\"brand\":\"Apple\",\"category\":\"laptops\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/6/thumbnail.png\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/6/1.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/6/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/6/3.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/6/4.jpg\"]},{\"id\":7,\"title\":\"Samsung Galaxy Book\",\"description\":\"Samsung Galaxy Book S (2020) Laptop With Intel Lakefield Chip, 8GB of RAM Launched\",\"price\":1499,\"discountPercentage\":4.15,\"rating\":4.25,\"stock\":50,\"brand\":\"Samsung\",\"category\":\"laptops\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/7/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/7/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/7/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/7/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/7/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":8,\"title\":\"Microsoft Surface Laptop 4\",\"description\":\"Style and speed. Stand out on HD video calls backed by Studio Mics. Capture ideas on the vibrant touchscreen.\",\"price\":1499,\"discountPercentage\":10.23,\"rating\":4.43,\"stock\":68,\"brand\":\"Microsoft Surface\",\"category\":\"laptops\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/8/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/8/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/8/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/8/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/8/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/8/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":9,\"title\":\"Infinix INBOOK\",\"description\":\"Infinix Inbook X1 Ci3 10th 8GB 256GB 14 Win10 Grey – 1 Year Warranty\",\"price\":1099,\"discountPercentage\":11.83,\"rating\":4.54,\"stock\":96,\"brand\":\"Infinix\",\"category\":\"laptops\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/9/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/9/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/9/2.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/9/3.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/9/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/9/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":10,\"title\":\"HP Pavilion 15-DK1056WM\",\"description\":\"HP Pavilion 15-DK1056WM Gaming Laptop 10th Gen Core i5, 8GB, 256GB SSD, GTX 1650 4GB, Windows 10\",\"price\":1099,\"discountPercentage\":6.18,\"rating\":4.43,\"stock\":89,\"brand\":\"HP Pavilion\",\"category\":\"laptops\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/10/thumbnail.jpeg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/10/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/10/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/10/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/10/thumbnail.jpeg\"]},{\"id\":11,\"title\":\"perfume Oil\",\"description\":\"Mega Discount, Impression of Acqua Di Gio by GiorgioArmani concentrated attar perfume Oil\",\"price\":13,\"discountPercentage\":8.4,\"rating\":4.26,\"stock\":65,\"brand\":\"Impression of Acqua Di Gio\",\"category\":\"fragrances\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/11/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/11/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/11/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/11/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/11/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":12,\"title\":\"Brown Perfume\",\"description\":\"Royal_Mirage Sport Brown Perfume for Men & Women - 120ml\",\"price\":40,\"discountPercentage\":15.66,\"rating\":4,\"stock\":52,\"brand\":\"Royal_Mirage\",\"category\":\"fragrances\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/12/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/12/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/12/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/12/3.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/12/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/12/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":13,\"title\":\"Fog Scent Xpressio Perfume\",\"description\":\"Product details of Best Fog Scent Xpressio Perfume 100ml For Men cool long lasting perfumes for Men\",\"price\":13,\"discountPercentage\":8.14,\"rating\":4.59,\"stock\":61,\"brand\":\"Fog Scent Xpressio\",\"category\":\"fragrances\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/13/thumbnail.webp\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/13/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/13/2.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/13/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/13/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/13/thumbnail.webp\"]},{\"id\":14,\"title\":\"Non-Alcoholic Concentrated Perfume Oil\",\"description\":\"Original Al Munakh® by Mahal Al Musk | Our Impression of Climate | 6ml Non-Alcoholic Concentrated Perfume Oil\",\"price\":120,\"discountPercentage\":15.6,\"rating\":4.21,\"stock\":114,\"brand\":\"Al Munakh\",\"category\":\"fragrances\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/14/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/14/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/14/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/14/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/14/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":15,\"title\":\"Eau De Perfume Spray\",\"description\":\"Genuine  Al-Rehab spray perfume from UAE/Saudi Arabia/Yemen High Quality\",\"price\":30,\"discountPercentage\":10.99,\"rating\":4.7,\"stock\":105,\"brand\":\"Lord - Al-Rehab\",\"category\":\"fragrances\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/15/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/15/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/15/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/15/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/15/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/15/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":16,\"title\":\"Hyaluronic Acid Serum\",\"description\":\"L'OrÃ©al Paris introduces Hyaluron Expert Replumping Serum formulated with 1.5% Hyaluronic Acid\",\"price\":19,\"discountPercentage\":13.31,\"rating\":4.83,\"stock\":110,\"brand\":\"L'Oreal Paris\",\"category\":\"skincare\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/16/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/16/1.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/16/2.webp\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/16/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/16/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/16/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":17,\"title\":\"Tree Oil 30ml\",\"description\":\"Tea tree oil contains a number of compounds, including terpinen-4-ol, that have been shown to kill certain bacteria,\",\"price\":12,\"discountPercentage\":4.09,\"rating\":4.52,\"stock\":78,\"brand\":\"Hemani Tea\",\"category\":\"skincare\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/17/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/17/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/17/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/17/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/17/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":18,\"title\":\"Oil Free Moisturizer 100ml\",\"description\":\"Dermive Oil Free Moisturizer with SPF 20 is specifically formulated with ceramides, hyaluronic acid & sunscreen.\",\"price\":40,\"discountPercentage\":13.1,\"rating\":4.56,\"stock\":88,\"brand\":\"Dermive\",\"category\":\"skincare\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/18/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/18/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/18/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/18/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/18/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/18/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":19,\"title\":\"Skin Beauty Serum.\",\"description\":\"Product name: rorec collagen hyaluronic acid white face serum riceNet weight: 15 m\",\"price\":46,\"discountPercentage\":10.68,\"rating\":4.42,\"stock\":54,\"brand\":\"ROREC White Rice\",\"category\":\"skincare\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/19/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/19/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/19/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/19/3.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/19/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":20,\"title\":\"Freckle Treatment Cream- 15gm\",\"description\":\"Fair & Clear is Pakistan's only pure Freckle cream which helpsfade Freckles, Darkspots and pigments. Mercury level is 0%, so there are no side effects.\",\"price\":70,\"discountPercentage\":16.99,\"rating\":4.06,\"stock\":140,\"brand\":\"Fair & Clear\",\"category\":\"skincare\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/20/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/20/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/20/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/20/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/20/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/20/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":21,\"title\":\"- Daal Masoor 500 grams\",\"description\":\"Fine quality Branded Product Keep in a cool and dry place\",\"price\":20,\"discountPercentage\":4.81,\"rating\":4.44,\"stock\":133,\"brand\":\"Saaf & Khaas\",\"category\":\"groceries\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/21/thumbnail.png\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/21/1.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/21/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/21/3.jpg\"]},{\"id\":22,\"title\":\"Elbow Macaroni - 400 gm\",\"description\":\"Product details of Bake Parlor Big Elbow Macaroni - 400 gm\",\"price\":14,\"discountPercentage\":15.58,\"rating\":4.57,\"stock\":146,\"brand\":\"Bake Parlor Big\",\"category\":\"groceries\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/22/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/22/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/22/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/22/3.jpg\"]},{\"id\":23,\"title\":\"Orange Essence Food Flavou\",\"description\":\"Specifications of Orange Essence Food Flavour For Cakes and Baking Food Item\",\"price\":14,\"discountPercentage\":8.04,\"rating\":4.85,\"stock\":26,\"brand\":\"Baking Food Items\",\"category\":\"groceries\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/23/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/23/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/23/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/23/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/23/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/23/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":24,\"title\":\"cereals muesli fruit nuts\",\"description\":\"original fauji cereal muesli 250gm box pack original fauji cereals muesli fruit nuts flakes breakfast cereal break fast faujicereals cerels cerel foji fouji\",\"price\":46,\"discountPercentage\":16.8,\"rating\":4.94,\"stock\":113,\"brand\":\"fauji\",\"category\":\"groceries\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/24/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/24/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/24/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/24/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/24/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/24/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":25,\"title\":\"Gulab Powder 50 Gram\",\"description\":\"Dry Rose Flower Powder Gulab Powder 50 Gram • Treats Wounds\",\"price\":70,\"discountPercentage\":13.58,\"rating\":4.87,\"stock\":47,\"brand\":\"Dry Rose\",\"category\":\"groceries\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/25/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/25/1.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/25/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/25/3.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/25/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/25/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":26,\"title\":\"Plant Hanger For Home\",\"description\":\"Boho Decor Plant Hanger For Home Wall Decoration Macrame Wall Hanging Shelf\",\"price\":41,\"discountPercentage\":17.86,\"rating\":4.08,\"stock\":131,\"brand\":\"Boho Decor\",\"category\":\"home-decoration\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/26/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/26/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/26/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/26/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/26/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/26/5.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/26/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":27,\"title\":\"Flying Wooden Bird\",\"description\":\"Package Include 6 Birds with Adhesive Tape Shape: 3D Shaped Wooden Birds Material: Wooden MDF, Laminated 3.5mm\",\"price\":51,\"discountPercentage\":15.58,\"rating\":4.41,\"stock\":17,\"brand\":\"Flying Wooden\",\"category\":\"home-decoration\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/27/thumbnail.webp\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/27/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/27/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/27/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/27/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/27/thumbnail.webp\"]},{\"id\":28,\"title\":\"3D Embellishment Art Lamp\",\"description\":\"3D led lamp sticker Wall sticker 3d wall art light on/off button  cell operated (included)\",\"price\":20,\"discountPercentage\":16.49,\"rating\":4.82,\"stock\":54,\"brand\":\"LED Lights\",\"category\":\"home-decoration\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/28/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/28/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/28/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/28/3.png\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/28/4.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/28/thumbnail.jpg\"]},{\"id\":29,\"title\":\"Handcraft Chinese style\",\"description\":\"Handcraft Chinese style art luxury palace hotel villa mansion home decor ceramic vase with brass fruit plate\",\"price\":60,\"discountPercentage\":15.34,\"rating\":4.44,\"stock\":7,\"brand\":\"luxury palace\",\"category\":\"home-decoration\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/29/thumbnail.webp\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/29/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/29/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/29/3.webp\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/29/4.webp\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/29/thumbnail.webp\"]},{\"id\":30,\"title\":\"Key Holder\",\"description\":\"Attractive DesignMetallic materialFour key hooksReliable & DurablePremium Quality\",\"price\":30,\"discountPercentage\":2.92,\"rating\":4.92,\"stock\":54,\"brand\":\"Golden\",\"category\":\"home-decoration\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/30/thumbnail.jpg\",\"images\":[\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/30/1.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/30/2.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/30/3.jpg\",\"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/30/thumbnail.jpg\"]}],\"total\":100,\"skip\":0,\"limit\":30}";
JsonNode jsonData = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonData));
```

The output will be:

```json
{
    "products": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "iPhone 9",
        "description": "An apple mobile which is nothing like apple",
        "price": 549,
        "discountPercentage": 12.96,
        "rating": 4.69,
        "stock": 94,
        "brand": "Apple",
        "category": "smartphones",
        "thumbnail": "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",
        "images": ["https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/1.jpg", "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/2.jpg", "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/3.jpg", "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/4.jpg", "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg"]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "iPhone X",
        "description": "SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD display with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...",
        "price": 899,
        "discountPercentage": 17.94,
        "rating": 4.44,
        "stock": 34,
        "brand": "Apple",
        "category": "smartphones",
        "thumbnail": "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/thumbnail.jpg",
        "images": ["https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/1.jpg", "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/2.jpg", "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/3.jpg", "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/2/thumbnail.jpg"]
    }, 
    ...
    ,{
        "id": 30,
        "title": "Key Holder",
        "description": "Attractive DesignMetallic materialFour key hooksReliable & DurablePremium Quality",
        "price": 30,
        "discountPercentage": 2.92,
        "rating": 4.92,
        "stock": 54,
        "brand": "Golden",
        "category": "home-decoration",
        "thumbnail": "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/30/thumbnail.jpg",
        "images": ["https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/30/1.jpg", "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/30/2.jpg", "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/30/3.jpg", "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/30/thumbnail.jpg"]
    }],
    "total": 100,
    "skip": 0,
    "limit": 30
}
```